# add custom field to control a menu class

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am usin Advanced Custom Fields plugin in wordpress. I want to create a custom feild in which the user will be able to add icon image url that will be the menu link beackground.
How can I do that inside the menu? can I add custom feild into menu control panel?
Can I change the div background by adding url of the icon?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a custom image field as explained here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/

You can then use the value for this field in an inline style tag in your header.php, e.g.:

.classname{
  background-image: url('')
}

Comment: Thank you I know I can make image field, But how will the menu take each class to a different list item link? This is the problem

Comment: sorry I thought you meant you were looking for a background image because you said "add icon image url that will be the menu link beackground."  I think you mean that you need to set a href for each of the images? Try using the WYSIWYG editor which might let you have an image then add a hyperlink.  Otherwise, for each image make 2 fields, one for the image and one for the link.